# Using custom icon within pInputText in primeng

Tags: angular, primeng

I have a use case similar to this: https://primeng.org/inputtext#icons
Instead of the `<i>` tag icon specified, I want to use a custom svg component on the right side of the element.

```html
<div class="p-input-icon-right">
          <custom-element [icon]="'loading'"></custom-element>
          <input
           pInputText
            class="input-text"
            [(ngModel)]="inputText"
            [placeholder]="'Please enter text'"
            type="text"
          />
        </div>
    </div>
```

However, this simply places the element on top of the input, and not within it.
Please help on how to proceed with resolving this.

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap the component in an `i` element:

```html
<span class="p-input-icon-right">
  <i>
    <custom-element [icon]="'loading'"></custom-element>
  </i>
  <input type="text" pInputText ... />
</span>
```

This also works for the `img` or raw `svg` elements.

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/bbm8qv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdemo%2Finput-text-icons-demo.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you inspect the styling for the icon styling in `.p-input-icon-right` CSS class, these are the crucial styling rule in order to place the icon element in the right side within the text box.

```
.p-input-icon-right > .p-icon-wrapper, .p-input-icon-right > i:last-of-type {
    right: 0.75rem;
    color: #6c757d;
}

.p-input-icon-left > i, .p-input-icon-left > .p-icon-wrapper, .p-input-icon-right > i, .p-input-icon-right > .p-icon-wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -0.5rem;
}
```

Thus, you should implement a similar CSS styling rule for the `custom-element` element.

```
.p-input-icon-right > custom-element:last-of-type {
  right: 0.75rem;
  color: #6c757d;
}

.p-input-icon-right > custom-element {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -0.5rem;
}
```

[Demo @ StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-7spb2j?file=src%2Fglobal_styles.css)